# PHP Random value in array ponderated

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have the following script:

```
$domain = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com'];
$domain = $domain[mt_rand(0, count($domain) - 1)];
```

It is possible to set a percentual value for each item coresponding to chances of being chosen.
For example, i want to have 75% chances to have a  $domain='gmail.com';.

Comment: `$i = mt_rand(0,100); if ($i<75) $domain = $domain[0];`

Comment: It uses Mersenne Twister algorithm. If you need customized one, why don't you create one?

Comment: $domain = ['gmail.com','gmail.com','gmail.com','gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com']; 4:2  now have more chance to get gmail. just a tricky not a right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the desired result.

My method doesn't demand that the total "chances" be 100; you can make your own decision on the value of the highest key.

The basis of my method is that the result (`$domain`) will be the array value with the lowest key that is not greater than the randomized number (`$pick`).

Here is an example to give gmail a 75% chance, and give yahoo & hotmail equal chances with the remaining 25%.

*Notice that `mt_rand()` starts at 1 versus 0 as commented under the question.

```
$domain_perc=array(
    750=>'gmail.com',    // between 1 & 750 = 75% chance
    875=>'yahoo.com',    // between 751 & 875 = 12.5% chance
    1000=>'hotmail.com'  // between 876 & 1000 = 12.5% chance
);

$pick=mt_rand(1,max(array_keys($domain_perc)));

foreach($domain_perc as $p=>$v){
    if($pick<=$p){
        $domain=$v;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can replace the `foreach()` code block with this one-liner:

```
$domain=current(array_filter($domain_perc,function($v,$k)use($pick){return $pick<=$k;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

As for customizing the input array, a simple way of expressing a 50%-25%-25% split would be:

```
$domain_perc=array(
    2=>'gmail.com',    // 1 and 2 of 4 = 50% chance
    3=>'yahoo.com',    // 3 of 4 = 25% chance
    4=>'hotmail.com'   // 4 of 4 = 25% chance
);
```

To set up a two-value array with a ~33% -vs- ~66% split:

```
$domain_perc=array(
    1=>'gmail.com',    // 1 of 3 = ~33% chance
    3=>'yahoo.com'     // 2 & 3 of 3 = ~66% chance
);
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thank you for the response!